# Can copyrighted characters be referenced to in an app description on one of the app stores?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

We're submitting and app to the app store and polishing up the app description. If you used something like "This is the James Bond of email services" would that be a copyright infringement?

Answer (score 1):

It can't be a copyright infringement, because names and other short phases are not protected by copyright.

It would only be a trademark infringement if a reasonable member of the public would be falsely led to believe that this product was somehow endorsed by or affiliated with the holder of the trademak, or that somehow the reputation of "james bond" was to be applied to this product. But when the name is pretty clearly used metaphorically, confusion seems unlikely and unreasonable, and so such a statement would not be an infringement.

Still it does seem rather silly, and there are probably better ways of saying "My app is really great!"

Answer (score -1):

No but it would be a trade mark infringement